# Abstract Keywords in Robot Framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

is it possible to implement abstract keywords, so that you can avoid duplicated "code" and also avoid technical arguments in the actual test implementation? It's also very important to me, that the abstract Keyword is not usable in any actual test implementation.

What I want to have is something like that:

```
*** Abstract Keywords ***
Open Menu Item
    [Arguments]     ${menu}
    Click Element    ${menu}

*** Keywords ***
Open Home
    Open Menu Item    Home

Open Setup
    Open Menu Item    Setup
```

Does Robot Framework support abstraction?

Comment: What meaning do you put in "abstract"? The commonly used one (see: Java) specifies there should be no implementation in such methods; and they are used within abstract classes, so inheritors must provide the actual implementation according to their shape. In your sample, that's not the case, you're reusung the implementation defined in the want-to-be abstract keyword; and there's no concept of classes in RF. So what are you actually trying to achieve? Disallow usage of keywords in test cases, only in other keywords?

Comment: I agree with @todor and want to add one comment. Robot Framework is not a programming language. These constructs you're using are alien to it's DSL for an obvious reason: they don't belong there. As mentioned by Bryan you can do much more in Python and this kind of approach really should be developed in that layer. Keep the Robot Framework side of things simple. So, please elaborate on _why_ this is so important to you in the Robot Framework layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: no

Robot framework has no concept of abstract keywords. You can certainly create new keywords that call other keywords like you do in your example, but there is no way to prevent someone from calling `Open Menu Item` directly if they know how to import it.

Slightly longer answer: yes, if you write keywords in python

You can certainly do what you want in python. Robot has a well-defined mechanism for how it knows which functions are keywords and which are not in a keyword library. Your abstract keyword can simply be a private function or method that doesn't get exported. Your exported keywords can use this function internally, but it won't be available directly as a keyword to your test cases.